# How to get ScriptIntrinsicBLAS KernelID

Tags: android, renderscript

I want to create ScriptGroup with some BLAS kernels, provided by ScriptIntrinsicBLAS.
But i can't find any ways to retrieve KernelIDs of these kernels. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ScriptIntrisicBLAS does not support ScriptGroup. There is no way to retrieve the KernelID for it.